# userDetailsService is not being called in spring security 6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to apply authentication to a springboot application using spring security 6 but the application stops running when I create a bean of AuthenticationProvider and add it to the filterChain. Otherwise, the application seems to be starting up.

Currently I have allowed all routes to be permitted for testing purposes.

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

@Autowired
private UserService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
private BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;



@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
    return daoAuthenticationProvider;

}

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .cors((cors) -> cors.configurationSource(apiConfigurationSource()))
        .csrf(csrf -> csrf.ignoringRequestMatchers("**"))
        .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
            .requestMatchers("**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        )
        .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
        .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
    return http.build();
}
```

}

**UserService.java**

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService{

@Autowired
UserRepoImpl userRepoImpl;

final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
final JwtService jwtService;
final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder encoder;

Integer getSessionDuration(RegisterUser user) {
    long sessionDuration = GlobalVariablesBackend.getRoleDuration(user.getRole());
    Integer intVal = Math.toIntExact(sessionDuration);
    return intVal;
}

@Override
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException 
{
    System.out.println("in user details service -> "+username);
    RegisterUser user = userRepoImpl.findByUsername(username);
    
    String jwtToken = jwtService.generateToken(user, user.getRole());
    
    AuthenticationResponse authResponse = new AuthenticationResponse();
    authResponse.setEmail(user.getEmail());
    authResponse.setRole(user.getRole());
    authResponse.setSessionDuration(getSessionDuration(user));
    authResponse.setToken(jwtToken);
    authResponse.setUsername(username);
    
    return authResponse;
}

}
```

**RegisterUser.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pushcode_users")
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class RegisterUser implements UserDetails{


@Id
@NotNull
@Email
@Column(unique=true)
String email;

@NotNull
String password;


@Column(name="created_date")
@CreationTimestamp
LocalDateTime createdDate;

@Column(name="last_login")
@UpdateTimestamp
LocalDateTime lastLogin;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
Role role;

@NotNull
@Column(name="username")
String username;

@Transient
String confirmPassword;

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return email;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
}

}
```

**AuthenticationResponse**

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuthenticationResponse extends RegisterUser{

@JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private String token;
private Role role;
private String username;
private String email;
private Integer sessionDuration;

}
```

From my understanding, the routes that need to be authenticated would be sent to AuthenticationProvider which calls loadUserByUsername that is implemented in UserService.
RegisterUser is the DAO for UserDetails and AuthenticationResponse is a DTO.

Would really appreciate any help or suggestions regarding this matter.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Also please remove httpBasic

Comment: returning JWTs to browser is dangerous. Dont do it. Dont use JWTs as a session

Comment: I'm not getting an error message even with try catch, that is an issue. The application doesn't just start up when I add the Authentication provider bean. Also, @Toerktumlare I was planning to send the jwt token in a secure httponly token so that the token itself isn't accessible on frontend but it can be read for request verification on backend. There shouldn't be any security issue if it isn't accessible in the frontend right?

Comment: Why even use a jwt then exposing information to the client that the client doesnt even need?

Comment: @Toerktumlare client requires the role, session duration but token is to be read in the backend to authorize all requests. There maybe better solutions but I thought this is a way to maintain each request Authorization tamper proof.

Comment: You are going to great lengths to build some home made strange custom built security. Building homemade security is in general not advised. Instead please follow a standard, like oauth2, openid connect, etc. Its for your own good.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your implementation, please take reference from this and let me know if you're still facing issues -

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserService userDetailsService;
    private final BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors().configurationSource(apiConfigurationSource())
            .and()
            .csrf().ignoringRequestMatchers("**")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .antMatchers("**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .httpBasic(withDefaults());
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource apiConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(encoder);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepoImpl userRepoImpl;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        RegisterUser user = userRepoImpl.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with username: " + username);
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                user.getAuthorities()
        );
    }
}

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "pushcode_users")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class RegisterUser implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Email
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;

    @NotNull
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    @CreationTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @Column(name = "last_login")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private LocalDateTime lastLogin;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Transient
    private String confirmPassword;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.name()));
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```